# Center an image and position text in a border layout

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to center an image and position text to south in a border layout.

Here's what I have so far

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FlowWindow extends JFrame {

    public FlowWindow() {
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        JPanel PanelImage = new JPanel();
        JPanel PanelText = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

This Section is where the image is supposed to be centered in the border.

```
        //calls the image and displays it to screen
        //supposed to center it also
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new
        ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("WITlogo.JPG"));
        JLabel label = new JLabel(imageIcon);
        PanelImage.add(label);
        contentPane.add(PanelImage, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This section is where the text is supposed to be position south in the border.

```
        //creates the string of text and displays to screen
        //supposed to position it in the south section of the border
        contentPane.add(new JLabel("Waterford Institude of technology"));
        PanelText.add(label);
        contentPane.add(PanelText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FlowWindow window = new FlowWindow ();
        window .setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setTitle("FlowWindow ");
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
        window .show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The easiest way to center a component is to use a GridBagLayout:

JPanel center = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(...);
center.add(image, new GridBagConstraints());
JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(...);

Then you add your components to the frame using:

add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(textLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

> Im really new to this

Then start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples that show the basics.

Don't forget to look at the tutorial table of contents for more information on all Swing basics.

Comment: I'll be sure to to look at the layout section in the Swing tutorial, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are using a FlowLayout and adding stuff using BorderLayout constraints (for example BorderLayout.SOUTH).

If you want an centered picture with text just below you need to have a panel inside another panel.

Comment: okay thank you for the tip, I hate to keep bothering you but could I ask you how thats done? Im really new to this and coding is not my strong point.